# How to build ipa file in windows?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, ipa, codemagic

I am developing a flutter application, I am using windows, I build the apk file. I wanted to build for the ios part. But it is not possible in windows and I use codemagic.

but code magic builds Runner.app file. and I use the [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) website to convert to ipa but file size exeeds.

Is there any other way to generate ipa file in windows.

Comment: I think diawi doesnt convert file to ipa. Its just an upload service. Sorry if i am wrong. You may try install on air. It has higher limit

Comment: For iOS, you need Xcode which is available only on a Mac.

Comment: I don't have Mac. Is there any way I can generate IPA files on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Diawi alternate solution, please check maybe it's helpful for you. Here you can upload large MB files.

https://www.installonair.com/

Comment: But here I can only upload IPA files. from code magic, I got only .app files. Is there any way I can convert Runner.app file to .ipa files(big files)

Answer (score 0):

With windows machine you can not build `ipa` files.

But there is an alternative solution to generate `ipa` files. For that use a CI/CD service like [Codemagic](https://codemagic.io/start/) using the steps described in this [example](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667).

- link your repository [github](https://github.com/), [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), etc.
- from settings > build for platforms > IOS
- change the `.app` file you received to `.zip` and `extract` it.
- You will find a file called `Runner.app`, put in a folder and compress it back.
- change the extension from `.zip` to `.ipa`.

Now you can get your `iOS` build `without mac` device

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a tool called Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI).

It allows you to access remote Mac OS to configure Xcode, retrieve your IPA file and publish your app...

You can check the online doc here: https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: According to Appollo support, "you will need an Apple Developer Account to create an IPA file."

Comment: Hey Mike, yes you are right. But I don't see your point here, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions in this article I got it.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667

Codemagic will send you an .app file via email.

Rename it so that it ends with .zip.

Extract it, and you’ll get a folder called Runner.app.

Create a folder called Payload and place Runner.app there.

Finally, compress the folder called Payload — this will be your IPA file (you may rename it to .ipa).